# how do I reformat this return statement to use lodash include instead of index of?

Tags: loops, filter, return, lodash, indexof

my linter is complaining about the usage of index Of so I wanted to change it.
`return applicableStatuses.indexOf(app.applicationStatus.code) !== -1;`

Comment: Use vanilla JS includes - `applicableStatuses.includes(app.applicationStatus.code)` or lodash's `_.includes(applicableStatuses, app.applicationStatus.code)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code -

```
applicableStatuses.includes(app.applicationStatus.code)
```

This should work like below example -

[image]